# Web3 and Smart Contracts usage

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain

**Hello everyone!**

I'm the new one in the blockchain stack and I would need some help to understand some technical details about blockchain, web3 etc.
I've read some theoretical parts and have tried to develop the simplest dapp but I still have some misunderstandings. I would be grateful if you corrected me. I decided to ask this question because each resource that I read describe the technology stack differently and I often get confused in understanding.

**So the first one - WEB3**

Web3 in my understanding is a big library that implements RPC requests. Whenever we call web3.(some function) we call RPC requests to a specific node in blockchain under the hood. So web3 just simplify our life and we don't need to think about RPC implementation. Did I get it right?

**The second one - smart contract.**

I don't fully understand when exactly to use it. For example, I would want to implement a bot that would check uniswap and pancakeswap exchanges and buy some coins for the lower price and sell it for the bigger. In this case, I need to use web3 to request some data about exchanges by putting the address as a parameter. Do I need to use smart contracts in this scenario somehow? I ask you about this because some resources say you need to use it others no.

Comment: 1/ Yes, 2/ You can write a bot in python, javascript, go, etc. without solidity. It depends on the problem you want to solve. For example if you execute several transactions and want all of them to succeed and revert otherwise using a contract is much easier.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @Ismael